# PHPStorm, 502 Bad Gateway при попытке запустить index.php

Tags: php, phpstorm

Установил недавно PHPStorm, создал в нем два файлика, index.html и index.php.
Оба с одинаковым текстом:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Тут крч название вкладки</title>
</head>
<body>
    Тут крч текст страницы
</body>
```

Запускаю html файл - все хорошо, открывается вкладка, все как надо.
Запускаю php файл - все плохо, открывается вкладка с "502 Bad Gateway"..
PHP установлен, CLI Interpreter (php-cgi) вродь как тоже присутствует...
[image: PHPStorm]

Comment: разве шторм ставит веб-сервер? он вроде открывает просто url с адресом вашего сервера. и если так то проблема в нем, смотрим логи веб-сервера и пхп еррор лога

Comment: Никакого стороннего веб-сервера не установлено, только PHPStorm.. Не сильно разбираюсь, но вроде-как есть встроенный веб-сервер: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/php-built-in-web-server.html . Или я не прав? До этого, запускал на Линуксе, с установленным только PHPStorm, PHP, php-cgi, и все работало, php файлы запускались...

Comment: Попробуйте во вкладе сервер. Указать localhost. Еще может быть такая трабла, что 80 порт занят чем то другим...

Comment: Не совсем понял, где именно найти эту вкладку?

Comment: Может ли быть проблема в том, что нету настроек php.ini?
http://s019.radikal.ru/i642/1706/6f/b175e0d751bc.jpg

Comment: Не у него нет встроеного php он запускает `php -S localhost:8000` где 8000 порт сервера. По этому вы должны настроить и сервер и порты и url. Но лучше зайти в директорию проекта и запустить `php -S localhost:8000`

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо установить php-cgi и указать в `Settings-> Languages & Frameworks -> PHP CLI Interpreter` версию вашего PHP.

Например для версии PHP 7.1:

```
sudo apt install php7.1-cgi
```

[image: Шаг 1]
[image: Шаг 2]

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, на сервере не хватает необходимых библиотек, для apache это  пакет libapache2-mod-php

Под убунту вы можете установить его командой:

```
sudo apt-get install php-cgi libapache2-mod-php
```

(установка последней версии)

И после этого попробовать переустановить php-cgi

Для Php 5:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-cgi
```

Для Php 7:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-cgi
```

Comment: In Russian, please. Это русскоязычный сайт и здесь принято общаться на русском языке.